# Is there a way for mysqli_fetch_assoc() to print there is no data when it is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to php, I'm trying to display a table with data from mySql, I'm using `while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){echo $row ...)` The problem I'm facing is when there is no data to display, it gives me a warning but I want it to display "There is no data to show at the moment". How can I do that?

Edit: it can show nothing too! but I don't want it to give me the warning.
I understand that `mysqli_fetch_assoc` needs one parameter. So, I'm asking if there is another function I can use instead, maybe?

Comment: Look into `mysqli_num_rows()`

Comment: The code you have shown should not give you a warning. What is that warning exactly?

Comment: I get this "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in .."

Comment: Do you mean all blank columns in a row?

Comment: That does not mean that there are no results, it means that your query failed completely. You should post the whole code concerning the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the number of rows returned by your select statement.

```php
if ($result->num_rows) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){
        // echo $row ...
    }
} else {
   echo "No results for this query!";
}
```